# Reloading builtins in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-importlib, built-in

I'm exploring the concept of namespace in Python and I can't explain the following: reloading `builtins` does not effectively reload the module. Here's an example:

```
import importlib as il
import os

import mymodule
mymodule.x = 6
print(mymodule.x)
mymodule = il.reload(mymodule)
print(mymodule.x)


import builtins
builtins.print = lambda x : os.system('echo hello')
builtins.print('hi')
builtins = il.reload(builtins)
builtins.print('hi')
```

Where mymodule simply contains the assignment `x = 5`. The output is:

```
6
5
hello
hello
```

Maybe it's a dummy question, but what is the reason for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload):

> It is generally not very useful to reload built-in or dynamically loaded modules. Reloading `sys`, `__main__`, `builtins` and other key modules is not recommended. In many cases extension modules are not designed to be initialized more than once, and may fail in arbitrary ways when reloaded.